# Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am getting this warning that I can not resolve:

> Invalid value for prop `value` on  tag. Either remove it from
>   the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.
>   For details

The following is the code I am using:

```
<FormItem validateStatus={NameError ? "error" : ""} help={NameError || ""}>
  {getFieldDecorator("Name", {
    initialValue: (()=>{this.state.Data.Name}),
    rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input the component name!" }]
  })(
    <Input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      name="Name"
      defaultValue={this.state.Data.Name}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
  )}
</FormItem>
```

My typescript interfaces look like this:

```
export interface IFieldEdition{
    Data:IFieldData
}

export interface IFieldData{
    Id?:number,
    Name?:string,
    Value?:string,
    Description?:string,
    CreatedDate?:Date,
    CreatedBy?:string,
    StatusId?: number
}
```

How can I resolve this? Any clue?

Comment: try to remove `defaultValue` from input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're using antd forms. From antd form [official document](https://ant.design/components/form/):

> After wrapped by getFieldDecorator, value(or other property defined by
>   valuePropName) onChange(or other property defined by trigger) props
>   will be added to form controls，the flow of form data will be handled
>   by Form which will cause:
>
> You shouldn't call setState manually, please use
>   this.props.form.setFieldsValue to change value programmatically.

Your use of `initialValue: (()=>{this.state.Data.Name}`, which calls setState might be the reason you're getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how that `getFieldDecorator` works, but seems to be that the problem might be you're passing a function as the `initialValue` prop.

Try replacing `initialValue: (()=>{this.state.Data.Name})` with `initialValue: this.state.Data.Name`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error while making an form with input, in my case the solution was very simple:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    value={this.state.term} 
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value.toLocaleUpperCase() })}
/>
```

What happened was that I simply forgot to call the method and had it like this:

```
toLocaleUpperCase
```

So, don't forget the parentheses at the end of any function call. Hope this helps.