# Warning: Invalid value for prop `logout` on <i> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm cleaning up all warning signs, it seems like antd or react doesn't have any docs on how to fix this warning sign. If I take out the antd import from the Header.js, the warning sign disappears.

Things I have tried: deconstructing of props and the links below:

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5226

[Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188706/invalid-value-for-prop-value-on-input-tag)

---

Here's what my code looks like:

**App.js**

```
import Header from "./components/header/header";

const App = () => {
   const [isAuth, updateLoginStatus] = useState(!!localStorage.getItem('user'));

   const logout = () => {
    updateLoginStatus(false);
  };

return (
    <Router>
      <div>
          <Route render={props => { const { staticContext, ...rest} = props; return (<Header {...rest} logout={logout} />)}}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
 );
};

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
import { Icon } from "antd";


const Header = props => {
   const { logout, history } = props

   const selectMenu = useCallback((option) => {

    switch (option) {
      case "logout":
        updateHeader({
          dashboard: false,
          details: false,
          alerts: false,
          logout: true
        });
        auhOut();
        logout();
        // isAuth = false;      
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  },[logout,history]);

export default Header;
```

Then it continues to give this warning:

> Warning: Invalid value for prop `logout` on <i> tag

Comment: the error seems to come from code you are not showing, most likely some JSX element...

Comment: does that value `logout: true` get's controlled by a component which is basically an `i` element?

Comment: it has nothing to do with `antd`, you don't have any components here

Comment: @SultanH. its controlled by an onClick from a styled-components div element.

Comment: @DennisVash every time I remove out the imported antd Icon the warning goes away...

Comment: the problem within the login function

Answer (score 0):

For me that the issue was the in the child component after receiving arguments from props using rest operator, I put it on the wrong component. So it cannot recognize these props and giving a warning to me.